# Definition of Veno-occlusive dysfunction

Tags: penis, urology, reproduction, erectile-dysfunction

Is "veno-occlusive dysfunction" the same as "Venous Leak" or are they different? Is one a subset symptom of another? This is regarding the subject of urology and erectile dysfunction.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For reasons [mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research) and in [How to Ask](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), we require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research.